# Negative look behind with or condition?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make `or` condition or 0 or 1 match in negative look behind but it is throwing error like `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

```
#method1
url = re.sub(r'(?<!(?:https:|http:))//','/',url)

#method2
url = re.sub(r'(?<!https?:)//','/',url)
```

How can i fix this issue using regex?

Example input

```
https://somedomain.com//having//extra//slash
```

Output

```
https://somedomain.com/having/extra/slash
```

I'm currently doing the following one, but I'm not sure for the all the cases

```
 url = re.sub(r'(?<!:)//','/',url)
```

Comment: So you want to change `ftp://user@example.com/` to `ftp:/user@example.com/`? That seems wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<!https:)(?<!http:)//
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9wcno1/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!https:)` - Negative lookbehind to make sure that current position is not preceded by `https:`
- `(?<!http:)` - Negative lookbehind to make sure that current position is not preceded by `http:`
- `//` - once the above 2 conditions are satisfied, match a double forward slash `//`

Replace all such `//` with `/`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think he wants to replace all the `//` either not preceded by `https:` or `http:` with `/`. This regex should do the job.

Comment: @Gurman: Are you mixing up the ones they do want to replace and the ones they don't?

Comment: @user2357112 My bad. You are right. Updated the comment

Comment: Okay, fair enough. :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ORing them would make them worthless, as that would match *everywhere*.